# How to get type of picked property instead of subset of supertype in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Assume there is a supertype `A`:

```js
type A = {
  q: {
    x1: string;
    x2: number;
  };
  p: number;
};

const aObj: A = {
  q: {
    x1: 'jj',
    x2: 3,
  },
  p: 5,
};

const fn = <T extends string & keyof A>(path: keyof A): Pick<A, T> => {
  return aObj[path];
};

const fn2 = <T extends string & keyof A>(path: keyof A): A[T] => {
  return aObj[path];
};
```

The code above raises the following error TS 2322:

```
 Type "number | { x1: string; x2: number; }" is not assignable to type "A[T]".
  Type "number" is not assignable to type "A[T]".
    Type "number" is not assignable to type "{ x1: string; x2: number; } & number".
      Type "number" is not assignable to type "{ x1: string; x2: number; }".
```

Now, I want to write a generic function `fn` that returns the *type* of the picked property `Pick<A, "p" | "q">`, that is `(number) | ({ x1: string, x2: number })`, depending on the specified generic argument.

However, `Pick` only returns a subset of all the picked properties of `A`.

Replacing `Pick` by square brackets does not seem to do the job either.

What is the right way to get the type of the picked property instead of just a subset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have something like:

```
const fn2 = <T extends keyof A>(path: T): A[T] => {
  return aObj[path];
};
```

You can check this at [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCOAuZb1QA8BGHAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBuPdAgJhxoFcBbAIwgpN0AXyFQwHHv0EpRKFAGMA9jXJQAhgHleAKxxxEqdNlz5CJKAHIdOywBpmhdlADMDke-E4ArA7nzlVWAoADMaVgQoAB4AFSgIAmAIGgATUigAawgQJRDYAD4ACjB1YAALHBiASn0AbRiAXQR80ygKCGBOChoNbR1akvKGplEgA)

As per your codebase, since there is no corelation between T and typeof path (i.e. keyof A). TypeScript is not able to determine what should be the return type. i.e. for path `p`, whether it should be `number` or it should be `{ x1: string, x2: number }`.